# Como exibir os dados em ordem decrescente?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como eu posso exibir os dados em **ordem decrescente** através do campo **`score`**, nesse código ele está exibindo do *menor para o maio*r, e eu gostaria de exibir do *maior para o menor*:

[image: Observem a print: http://i.imgur.com/7MTI5WR.jpg]

---

```
<?php 


        $pasta = "C:\Users\Vinicius\Desktop\Vinicius\SS Oficial by Vinicius\scriptfiles\Scores"; 
        $classificar = "Score";  

        $jogadores= -1; 
        $dadosjogador = array(); 
        $handlepasta = opendir($pasta); 


        while(($nickname  = readdir($handlepasta)) !== false) { 
                if(($nickname !=".") && ($nickname  !="..") && ($nickname != "index.htm") && ($nickname !="info")) { 
            $jogadores++; 
                        $contaaberta    = parse_ini_file($pasta ."/". $nickname); 
                        $nickname      = substr($nickname, 0,strlen($nickname)-4); 
                        $dadosjogador[$jogadores] =  array($contaaberta[$classificar] ,$nickname ); 
                } 
        } 



        array_multisort ($dadosjogador, $dadosjogador); 



        foreach ($dadosjogador as $jogador_atual) { 
                echo "<b>Jogador</b>:  ".$jogador_atual[1]."    |    <b>Score</b>:  ".$jogador_atual[0]."  <br>"; 
        } 
?>
```

Comment: coloque isso como resposta! e não editando a pergunta! ou seja, isso faz parte de uma resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Solução:

```
array_multisort ($dadosjogador, SORT_DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso em especifico o [**usort**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) com uma função também resolveria:

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){
    return $b[0] > $a[0];
});
```

sendo `$b[0]` e `$a[0]` é a posição dos valores, tendo então a opção de colocar a coluna que deve ser ordenada.